# Where condition of float column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this table in my SQL Server database

[image: tblImage]

The type of `Gisx` and `Gisy` columns is `FLOAT`.

When I want to select from this table like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM TblImage  
WHERE GisX = 57.2938107
```

everything is fine, but when the digits after the point are more than 7 digits, the result of selection is going to be nothing while there is such field in the table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TblImage  
WHERE GisX = 38.0752152407368
```

I know maybe it is because of the problem in float but is there any way to fix the problem?

Comment: @atabrizi you retrieve result based on exact match either it is 7 or 5 digit after decimal. If you get other result either it is exact matched or not then you can apply >= or <=. Please check the url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e98bf8ceeb3cb048b36ae471fdf2b4db

Comment: @RahulBiswas I can not use >= or <= because I want exact match

Comment: @GSerg . how can I fix the problem. is it possible or I should change the tpe?

Comment: It is not a problem, it is how floating point numbers are designed. If you want exact matches, use `numeric`.

Comment: *because I want exact match* - but you're using a data type that stores *approximations*, so yes you need to use decimal / numeric.